# Why does overriding loadView in UITableViewController fix tableView being associated with multiple view controllers crash?

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uitableview, uiapplicationdelegate

I have an app that was crashing (in iOS 6 only) when the app was loaded with the following error:

```
Application windows are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'UIViewControllerHierarchyInconsistency', reason: 'A view can only be associated with at most one view controller at a time!
View <UITableView: 0xc21a800; frame = (0 20; 320 460); clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = W+H; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0xbfb9d50>; layer = <CALayer: 0xbfb9720>; contentOffset: {0, 0}> is associated with <RootViewController: 0xbfbbb40>. Clear this association before associating this view with <RootViewController: 0xbfac010>.'
```

My applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions looks like this:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    // Add root nav controller below everything else
    RootViewController *rootViewController = [[RootViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
    rootViewController.title = @"My App";
    NSArray *sectionNames = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Sec 1", @"Sec 2", @"Sec 3", nil];
    rootViewController.sectionNames = sectionNames;

    UINavigationController *aNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:rootViewController];
    self.navigationController = aNavigationController;

    if ([self.window respondsToSelector:@selector(setRootViewController:)]) {
        self.window.rootViewController = aNavigationController;
    } else {
        [self.window addSubview:aNavigationController.view];
    }

    // Add fake loading image
    NSString* imageName = @"Default-Portrait.png";
    theImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:imageName]];
    theImageView.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,320,480);

    [self.window addSubview:theImageView];

    return YES;
}
```

RootViewController is just a subclass of UITableViewController with nothing interesting in it other than this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.tableView.delegate = self;
    self.tableView.allowsSelection = YES;
    self.userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
}
```

I have a .xib file for it but am not using it for initialization and this error is there whether that file exists or not.

Astoundingly, the error goes away when I add this to RootViewController:

```
- (void)loadView {
    [super loadView];
}
```

It's [super loadView] that fixes the problem, and I shouldn't even be calling that. Why??

Comment: Do you have a RootViewController in your storyboard? btw, docs say you shouldn't call super in your implementation of loadView.

Comment: No, I don't have any storyboard at all in this app. Thanks for the tip about not calling [super loadView]. I took that out but without it I get an EXC_BAD_ACCESS when referring to self (self.tableView.delegate = self) in viewDidLoad.

Comment: No, no MainWindow.xib. I created all of the views programmatically in this project. I will likely rewrite the app to use .xib files soon as that seems to cause fewer problems these days.